# Authentication Options in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, authentication

Hi im curious to get some input on different username/password authentication options in nodeJS and their pros and cons. I have been reading up on PassportJS but want to know other peoples opinions regarding this subject.

I come from .net and i have been using their forms authentication so perhaps similar "cookie authentication" process would be a nice option.

Comment: what kind of security layer would you want to implement? A simple username / password with hashed password in the backend?

Comment: In .net they use AES, perhaps something on the same level.

Comment: yeah, i would guess a normal bcrypt plugin with nodejs would do the job you are aiming for